# Why the network share on a windows 7 machine with two names cannot be accessed without user credentials?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a windows 7 machine with 3 network cards. The IPs are something like follows.

```
192.168.2.10
192.168.2.11
192.168.2.12
```

In the C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file I have the following entries.

```
192.168.2.11    macname1
192.168.2.12    macname2
```

lmhosts file also contains the following entries.

```
192.168.2.11    macname1    
192.168.2.12    macname2
```

If I ping the macname1 and macname2 from within this machine, I get to see the IP addresses properly.

However I have a problem in accessing the shares.
I have a share xyz in this machine.
I can open this share in explorer on the same machine with \\192.168.2.11\xyz and \\192.168.2.12\xyz
However if I try \\macname1\xyz or \\macname2\xyz, it asks for user name and password to connect.

How to resolve this problem?

Please note that this is a virtual machine and the network cards are connected to a virtual network. But I'm not sure if that matters. Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I have added multiple machine names as given in [this post](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/how-can-i-define-multiple-netbios-names-machine).

```
1. Start the registry editor (regedt32.exe)
2. Move to HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
3. From the Edit menu select "Add Value"
4. Set the type to REG_SZ is you want one extra name or REG_MULTI_SZ if you want more than one and enter a name of OptionalNames. Click OK
5. You will then be prompted for a value. Enter the other name (or names if type REG_MULTI_SZ, one on each line) you want it to be known as and click OK.
6. Close the registry editor
7. Reboot the machine
```

With this procedure my machine has two names known at the NETBIOS level and then the connection to shared folder via any machine name works well.